# Bootstrap modal not working inside jquery script?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

> I am writing one jquery script inside that script having some
>   bootstrap code for modal but its not working. If i used code outside
>   script then its working only.

```
else if(arrayData[j].key=="47")
 {
    var  country = "Poland";
    var  color = "LIGHTSALMON";

                    '</a>|';
      check+= '<a  class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Poland</a>|';
      '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">'+
          '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
            '<div class="modal-content">'+
              '<div class="modal-header">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
                '<h4 class="modal-title">Select Language</h4>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="modal-body">'+
                '<a class="btn btn-success"  style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/poland_pdf/'+arrayData[j].value+'">ENGLISH</a>'+
                '<a class="btn btn-success"  style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/polish_pdf/'+arrayData[j].value+'">POLAND</a>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
              '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';   

 }
```

above code is inside jquery script. If i used this modal outside script its working. Is there any other way like using `DIV` outside of script. but i dont know how to use jquery variables outside script with php code.

Comment: can you double check the code after LIIGHTSALMON

Comment: I resolve my issue. i missed my variable `check+=` before div its working now

Comment: cool !! best wishes